# Background Video in React

Tags: css, reactjs, video, background

I'm following this CSS Trick blog to set a background video for a react project but it's not working.

https://css-tricks.com/full-page-background-video-styles/

```js
//Video.jsx

<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
//index.css

#bgvid {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with react it worked quite fine with me.All i had to do was to use the video element in react.

1. First, import the desired background video which i assume is in your assets folder.For instance:

```js
import Myvideo from "./assets/home/myvideo.mp4";


export default function Video(){
return (


    <div className='myvideo'>
      <video src={Myvideo} autoPlay loop muted />
      <div className="content">
      <h1>Hi</h1>
      <p>This is my background video</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      
     );
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

import Myvideo from "./assets/home/myvideo.mp4";

2. Include the the video element in your return body.
3. style your css as below.

```css
//css
.myvideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

4. Your video should now play at the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. I had to use camelCase for the JSX.

```
    <video 
       autoPlay 
       loop
       playsInLine
       className="video-background" 
       muted
     >
```

## html tags explaination

- autoplay: play video automatically
- loop: loop the video
- className: to use it in the css
- muted: mute the video
- playsinline: for mobile. it lets the video plays in-line, not forcing the full screen video play

## css tags explaination

- z-index: -1 => it means that I want the video to be 1 layer behind the web content
- width: full screen width
- backround: rgba(0,0,0,0) => transparent background
- (but if you use react-bootstrap you can just use jsx tag, `bg-transparent`)